# Как сделать в wordpress, если категория "x", то svg "x"?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть страница, где разные категории и там разные svg

У меня для вывода постов (карточек товаров) такой код:

```html
<?php
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('category_name=for_heating&showposts=-1' . '&paged='.$paged);
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="col-lg-4 <?php $posttags = get_the_tags();
     if( $posttags ){
     foreach( $posttags as $tag ){
     echo $tag->slug. ' ';
     }
     } ?>">
  <div class="card_item" id="spoiler1">
   <div class="content-item">
    <div class="title_svg">
     <h4 class="h4_cards">
      <?php the_title() ?>
     </h4>
    <div class="svg_card">
     <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', $svg_attr ); ?> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <p class="p6">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

`<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', $svg_attr ); ?>` - через такую штуку сейчас выводится картинка ( из админки)
На выходе получается svg, но в теге img, а через него нельзя поменять заливку

Ломаю голову и не могу придумать как прописать, что если категория x, то выводим svg x и при hover fill: #новыйцвет , если категория y, то y и так далее

Вы поможете любой идеей или хотя бы наброском!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Получите урл `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` и выведите контент:

```
$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( ... )
echo file_get_contents( $url );
```